# xhr Request call multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating one profile page which have one logo using image tag. I need to change the logo by clicking the image and select the new one.

**Current Implementation:**

1. I used file upload control and hide the element.
2. When user clicks the logo i called the click event of file upload.
3. In the onChange event of file upload control, I submit the closes form
4. I track the form submit event and send using xhr request for Ajax post with image

**Html Code:**

```
<div align="center">
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateImage", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "successImage" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
    <img alt="User Pic" src="@Model.user.ImagePath" id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive">
    <input id="profile-image-upload" name="image" class="hidden" type="file" onchange="$(this).closest('form').submit();">
    <div id="imageError" class="field-validation-error" style="height:100%; display:none;">click here to change image</div>                               
   }
 </div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$(function () {
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var form = e.target;
 if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
    var file = $(form).find('#profile-image-upload');
    if (!validateImage(file)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (form.dataset.ajax) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        successIamge(result);
        return false;
      }
    };
    xhr.send(new FormData(form));
    }
  }
 });

$('#profile-image1').on('click', function () {
  $('#profile-image-upload').click();
});

function successImage(result) {
  if (!result || !result.resultCode) return; //If result is null not handled or Validation handled via ModelState
  if (result.resultCode == 1) {
    // $('profile-image1').attr('src', result.resultValue);
     location.reload();
        }
  else {
     location.href = "/Error/Index?errorMessage=" + result.resultMessage;
        }
 }
```

**Current Issue :**

Process worked successfully but after response the image, again the post request is fired.

**Work Around I did:**

From  guest271314 question i found that i din't prevent default form submit. So now added the prevent default to the submit. I changed the code source above.
   Now the image is not updated with new image i got the response from the upload. So now i changed the sucessLogo method to reload the page got the new image.

Now please suggest any other method to update image with out reload the page

Comment: What do you mean by _"again the post request is fired"_? Does `<form>` have `data-ajax` attribute set? Have you prevented the default action of form submission? Is `successImage` called twice?; at `OnSuccess = "successImage"` and `onchange="$(this).closest('form').submit();`?

Comment: i mean the post method is fired again after success the image upload. so again the image is uploaded. Sorry where you prevent the default action. Actually when form submit i used the custom code to attach the image

Comment: if i use e.preventDefault() after xhr.send() method, the uploaded image not showing in image tag. but all other success

Comment: You appear to be calling `successImage` twice?

Comment: @guest271314 , the ajax post call twice. The reason is i didn't prevent the default sumit like you told. But my json response have the new image path and didnt updated the logo image. Here i need to relaod the page to get the new one. Any other option? i updated this details in the question

Comment: What is purpose of substituting `$('profile-image1').attr('src', result.resultValue);` for 
     `location.reload();` ? Could you remove `OnSuccess = "successImage"` an call `event.preventDefault()` within `.submit()` handler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118682/discussion-between-akhil-and-guest271314).

Comment: yes. i removed that. Afer upload the image i got the new path in result.resultvalue. result json object. I need to change the image with new image. For that i used this code $('profile-image1').attr('src', result.resultValue); but not updating. When reloading only updated